# pencil tip stuck in charger port of iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, lightning

My 2 year old stuck a pencil tip in the port charger of my iPhone 6. I am now not able to insert the charger into the port. I tried removing the graphite with a nail file but it won't come out.

What are my options at this point?

Comment: A Needle should do it.

Comment: Maybe a can of duster(canned air)

Comment: A picture of the object and the size of the file you tried might really help here. Shaking it loose is ideal if you don't drop the phone. Also - if you can edit this to explain how hard it will be to get to a technican - we can determine if it's worth you learning how to safely get it out or if you can just swing by an Apple store tomorrow and have then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Two options: Superglue / Toothpick, Apple Store

What has worked for me in the past, is to use a toothpick and some superglue.

Dab one end of the toothpick into some superglue. Use as little as possible at first. Then very, very carefully, place the toothpick onto the graphite pencil tip that is stuck in the headphone jack. Hold the toothpick in place for about a minute or two, and then gently attempt to pull / remove the pencil tip.

If it remains stuck, try again, with a bit more superglue, and hold the toothpick in place for an extra minute or so.

Be careful not to drip excess glue into the headphone jack.

If you can take your iPhone into an Apple Store and have a technician look at it, they may be able to remove the pencil tip with either tweezers, or condensed air. If they are unable to remove it, they may label it "Accidental Damage" and provide you with replacement options at a cost.

Again, the toothpick / superglue has worked for me in the past. However, in Apple's eyes, taking the iPhone into an Apple Store is the best bet.

Comment: The toothpick is a good idea as it's non conducting. Otherwise... Yikes! What would happen if a drip/dab/smidgen of superglue came off the toothpick and stayed in the port???

Answer (score 1):

Try something like fishing line or insulated wire. The idea is to put it's end into the port, make it go around the tip and go out at it's other side (U shape). Now gently pull out the loop you've made around the tip using 2 line/wire's ends looking from the port and it should go out.